# Backbone.js — Collection in anonymous view instance requesting more than once on fetch

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js, router

I am using a Router to instantiate my views anonymously so I can simply render them on initialization.

```js
window.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
    ...
  },

  index: function() {
    new SchoolsView();
  },

  ...

});
```

```js
window.SchoolsView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    events: {
        'click .more a': 'loadMore'
    },

    initialize: function() {    
        this.collection = new schoolList();

        this.collection.bind('add', this.add, this);
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function() {
      ...
    },

    add: function(school) {
      ...
    },

    loadMore: function() {
      this.collection.loadMore();
      return false;
    }
});
```

The view's collection, which is constructed inside of the view's constructor, has a computed `url` property that supports a pagination "offset" parameter on each request. Before each "next page" request, the "offset" parameter is incremented by one for the server to return the next offset of results. The first `collection#fetch()` uses the default "offset" value from the initialize method, it is incremented once the method `collection#loadMore()` is invoked.

```js
window.schoolList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.offset = 1;
  },

  url: function() {
    return this.baseUrl()+'?offset='+this.offset;
  },

  pageInfo: function() {
    var info = {
      total: this.total,
      offset: this.offset,
      pages: Math.ceil(this.total / 9),
      more: false
    };

    if (this.offset < info.pages) info.more = this.offset + 1;

    return info;
  },

  loadMore: function() {
    if (!this.pageInfo().more) return false;
    this.offset += 1;
    return this.fetch({ add: true });
  }
});
```

It was working great until I noticed after navigating back and forth several times from the default route, which implements the view and collection in question, to another one; and clicking the element that invokes the collection's `collection#loadMore()` method, `fetch()` was called the number of times I navigated back to the default router.

I expected it only to call `fetch()` once, but it easily calls the method 2 or more times after navigating. Is this because the instance isn't being destroyed after I change routes and navigate back? If so, how do I properly clean up the object after I no longer need it?

Comment: are you expecting fetch to be called once, period? or once for each time you hit the default route?

Comment: Each time I hit the default route. I want it to fetch new data on the default route no matter if it's been accessed before.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        ...
    },

    index: function() {
    var collection = new schoolList(),
        view = new SchoolsView({
            collection: collection
        });

    this
        .trigger('destroy_index')
        .bind('destroy_index', function() {
            collection.reset();
            view.remove();
        });
    },

    ...

});

window.SchoolsView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    initialize: function() {    
        this.collection.bind('add', this.add, this);
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Could you give better context to this code paste? Why are you both triggering and invoking the 'destroy_index' event on route access?

Comment: This will destroy old observers before binding new one